Deleting resource of a django model with foreign key
I have following django models :
class ModelA(models.Model) : # fld1, fld2
class ModelB(models.Model) :
    fld_a1 = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, related_name='modela_1')
    fld_a2 = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, related_name='modela_2')
    # other fields

Now when I delete resource from ModelB, how to make sure that the corresponding foreignkey objects from ModelA are also deleted

Are you sure a Foreign Key (N to 1) is what you want in Model B?
you can have 3 objects of Model B, each one with the same Foreign Key to Model A, and if you delete one of those objects you will need to delete the other Model B objects or set their value of the Foreign Key as null.

What do you mean by "delete resource from ModelB"?

A ForeignKey can specify an on_delete action which takes place if the object that it is referencing gets deleted. The common ones are to delete this object automatically, to prevent (abort)  the deletion of the object that is being referenced, or to set the field to null. A foreignkey is equal to null or the primary key of the referenced object (usually its integer pk).
